# Create a RSS using Views of a content type

Tags: 7, views, feeds

How to configure Views to display a RSS feed of certain content types, which contains several articles?

I would like the RSS to have **1 news feed for 1 content type**. How to config it?

I can only set the feed to display all article titles in 1 news feed, which does not make sense.

The sample XML is like this:

```
<news>
    <article>
        <title>Some Title Here</title>
        <content><![CDATA[Some Contents here]]></content>
        <pubDate>2011-09-20 10:01</pubDate>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>Another Title Here</title>
        <content><![CDATA[Other Contents here]]></content>
        <pubDate>2011-09-20 11:01</pubDate>
    </article>
</news>
```

where the 2 articles above is in certain content type.

Comment: Not very clear. Could you provide a better description (or an example) of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MaciejZgadzaj: I have updated the question for further explanation. Please see if it is clear or not.

Comment: Personally I'm still not sure what you're looking for. You're saying you "would like the RSS to have 1 news feed for 1 article", but from your example it seems to me that you want do have one feed for one content type (listing all/specific number of nodes from this content type).

Comment: @MaciejZgadzaj: Yes, to correct my question, I would like to have 1 news feed for 1 content type. Can you explain to me how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comment exchange under the question - just add a new view showing "content" of type <your_type>, tick "Create a page" and "Include an RSS feed" underneath. This will give you a feed with list of all nodes of a specific type. Then just play with all other settings to get what you need, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is only to create a custom RSS templates from views.  Unfortunately not allot of data is passed on, but I believe content types do pass on, though you would want to order the RSS view by content type first.